# How to get List of List of Objects with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can't get my head around this problem.

### Problem

I want to writhe this with Java streams:

```
List<Manufacturer> manufacturers = ... // List of Manufacturer-Objects

List<List<Car>> cars = new ArrayList<>();
for (Manufacturer man : manufacturers) {
   cars.add(man.getCars()); // Let's just say getCars() returns a List of cars.
}
```

I think with Java Streams it should look like the following:

```
List<List<Car>> cars = manufacturers.stream().
   .flatMap(man -> man.getCars().stream())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Errors

But my IDE says the following `no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that List<Event> conforms to Stream<? extends R>`

And the java compiler:

```
java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      java.util.List<elements.Car> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>)
```

Any solutions for this? 
Thanks!

Comment: `List<List<Car>> cars = manufacturers.stream()
   .map(man -> man.getCars())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the second "stream" but this returns still the same error. I will edit the question.

Comment: `List<List<Car>> result = manufacturers.stream()
    .map(Manufacturer::getCars)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala This was the correct answer. I was one click away from marking it as the approved answer :)

Comment: Ohh I deleted since it is a trivial answer. Let me retract it

Comment: Yes it was quite trivial, sorry :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the `flatMap` operator which takes all the lists and gives you a `List<Car>`. Instead you have to use the `map` operator to get the desired result. Here's how it looks.

```
List<List<Car>> result = manufacturers.stream()
    .map(Manufacturer::getCars)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```